# Form Data Processed in Controller or Model : Which is better?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm just wondering which one is better, or more recommended for processing form data.

```
// Controller
// validation etc
$data = array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'), '... etc');
$this->user_model->insert($data);

// Model
function insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
}
```

or

```
// Controller
// validation etc
$this->user_model->insert();

// Model
function insert($data){
    $data = array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'), '... etc');
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
}
```

I'm using the second method at the moment. Despite no problem for inserting, I have to say it's not very suitable for updating. I end up having to create new methods to update only certain fields of a table. I'm thinking of changing to the first method. I'm just wondering whether anyone can help give clearer pros and cons of each method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that Models and Libraries should be doing most of the heavy processing, however I believe that Model and Library methods should be as re-usable as possible, and the Controller should act as traffic director, deciding which models to call and what data to send to them.

So in your example, the former makes more sense.  Think about it this way -- isn't it possible that you may want to add a user some other way, other than via form posts?

Another option, if you want best of both worlds, create a wrapper function in the model:

```
// Controller
// validation etc
$this->user_model->insert_from_post();

// Model
function insert_from_post(){
    $data = array('name'=>$this->input->post('name'), '... etc');
    $this->insert('users',$data);
}

function insert($data){
    $this->db->insert('users',$data);
}
```

Of course in this example it seems excessive.  But in more complex applications you quickly benefit from being able to reuse functions that have established, predictable and tested results.

Comment: yeah, i agree with your answers. I think it's better to have 2 functions for inserts or updates, one is to process from a form post, and another one is to insert/update only what's necessary. Insert/Update all data is only ever used by a form, while for things like set user's status/active/activation_date may need a flexible update function. What do you think?

Comment: Sounds right.  In some cases I've built complex models and made use of method chaining syntax ala the active record class, which makes controller code look really nice: `$this->User_model->set_username('Henson')->set_email('whatever@whoever.tdm')->insert();`

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Controllers to a minimum.  Consider using your controllers for passing data to and from your views/models.  Also I would suggest doing all the heavy work in your models, html encoding, date parsing etc.  The only work your view should do is either spit out variables or loop through them

Codeigniter 2.1 allows you to put all your form_validation configs into one file inside application/config/form_validation.php

So really all your controller needs to do is say

```
if ($this->form_validation->run('auth/register')) {/** interact with your models or libraries (keep the  heavy stuff outside **/ )}else{//show form}
```

**Edit: @catfish**

Keeping the controller to a minimum is not the same as saying "dont put anything in your controller".  If you notice above I did include the form validation in the controller, however you can exclude the form_validation config from your controller.

A minimal Controller would look like so.

```
class someclass extends CI_Controller
{
 //The form validation rules go inside the application/config/form_validation.php
 //and is called automatically once the class/method is init

 public function __construct()
 {
     parent::__construct();
 }

 public function form()
 {
    $this->load->view('templates/public', array('content'=>'form_view.php'));
 }

 public function validate()
 {
      if($this->form_validation->run('someclass/validate'))// optionally pass the config key
      {
          if(Model::method($this->input->post()))
          {
              //do something positive
          }else
          {
             $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $this->lang->line('some_error'));
             redirect('/');
          }
      }else
      {
         $this->form();//show form again
      }
 }

 public function work_with_model()
 {
     $this->load->view('_index', array(
        'model_data'=> model::method()// do all looping, html encoding, time/date parsing etc and only send back a string or an array/object ready for output
     ));
 }

}
```

application/config/form_validation.php

```
$config = array('someclass/validate'=>array(
     array('field'=>'Field', 'label'=>'Label', 'rules'=>'trim|required|xss_clean|serialize')
));
```

The point I was trying to make was only use your controller as a pass between, with minimal logic

Comment: but what about for updating some fields of a table? Let's say users table has name,age,address,phone,status. A common update form will have name,age,address,phone field, so a common update function will update 4 of these fields. Then for the status, I may have a function set_status($user_id) which basically updates only status where user_id = $user_id. That's what I've been doing anyway, so I wonder if that's a good thing or not. But this leaves the controller very easy to read.

Comment: All you need to do is take your $this->input->post() array, modify it however you need, by building a new array with modified values, then pass that along to your model/library.  If all you need to do is modify one of the keys, say you want to serialize it, you should be able to do this in your form_validation config markup.  ie: 'rules' => 'trim|required|xss_clean|serialize'

Comment: @philip I completely disagree with keeping your controllers to a minimum. If that were the case, then what's the point of having them? IMHO, The model is for data access only, while the controller handles the form_validation, etc. See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html

Comment: @Philip I think adding anything (most possibly an array) inside Model::method($arr) actually is more like first method :) and I guess what catfish said is true, too. Controllers should be doing all the heavy tasks like preparing data to be passed to models or views. The form_validation actually belongs to controller's scope too, don't you agree? Putting it in the config basically removes the necessity of calling it in the controllers, but otherwise, we have to do it in controllers. I guess I'm gonna stick with the first method from now on unless there are other pros and cons of each method